# TFIDF using Apache Mahout have "Job failed!" when app run

Tags: java, eclipse, machine-learning, mahout, tf-idf

I want to run simple app using Apache Mahout from http://technobium.com/tfidf-explained-using-apache-mahout/. But! When app running, i have some exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DictionaryVectorizer.startWordCounting(DictionaryVectorizer.java:369)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DictionaryVectorizer.createTermFrequencyVectors(DictionaryVectorizer.java:180)
    at my.package.text_extractor.clasterization.TFIDFTester.calculateTfIdf(TFIDFTester.java:97)
    at my.package.text_extractor.clasterization.TFIDFTester.main(TFIDFTester.java:35)
```

But, I don't know **how to fix it**. Maybe you know how to fix this problem in **Apache Mahout lib**? Please, give me some idea!

**Configuration:**
*Windows 7 x64,* *Eclipse Oxigen 1a, Maven, Mahout-core-0.9*

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my program that was based on the same sample code (technobium) when I made my analyzer inner class and constructor non public. They are instantiated by reflection (yuck).

Unfortunately the exception that gets thrown is extremely unhelpful.